# Солнце с газировкой?

Tags: контекст, культура

> Я читал одну книгу, повесть **про** лётчиков времён войны... И там, в этой повести, один из наших пилотов всегда уходил в сторону солнца после атаки, поэтому его никто не мог сбить. Он потом садился на аэродром, где базировались американские лётчики, тогда мы воевали вместе. И вот американцы пили своё виски, а он всегда просил в столовой **немного солнца с газировкой**.

(Владимир Березин - Путевые знаки)

Два вопроса:

1. Почему говорится *повесть **про** лётчиков*, а не *повесть **о** лётчиках*
2. Что это за *солнце с газировкой*? Это какой-то коктейль или напиток?

Comment: наверно летчики, а не летники

Comment: В оригинале *"повесть про лётчиков" ... "американские лётчики"*. А вот что подразумевается под "солнцем с газировкой" не знаю.

Comment: Как видно из контекста, это своего рода шутка. Летчик использовал в бою солнце и на земле в некотором роде высказывал пожелание, чтобы всегда было солнечно. Само выражение вроде бы нигде более не встречается.

Comment: `Про летчиках` Is incorrect. You should use `про летчиков` or `о летчиках`.

Comment: @user4419802 Well, not necessarily.  There's [Sun Drop Soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Drop) drink. The formula was patented in 1930, but the drink itself technically wasn't introduced until 1949 - yet I wouldn't be surprised if it's related.

Comment: @AleksG: it's obvious from the context it's just a word play. The pilot drinks nothing but sun-lit raindrops which he catches with his lips, and jokingly refers to them as "sun-soda". A Soviet pilot would hardly be aware of an American soda brand in 1940's.

Comment: Значит `спрашивать о +ком` и `спрашивать про кого` то же?

Comment: @marmistrz: Rosenthal considers *про* colloquial, but there is no difference really nowadays

Comment: про vs о http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/52/usage-of-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-instead-of-%D0%BE/416#416

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the author talks about "Sun-Soda" (*Сода-солнце*), a short story  by Mikhail Ancharov:

> Его звали "Сода-солнце".
>
> Американские лётчики, участники челночного полета, которые отбомбились над Берлином и теперь пили у стойки на нашей базе, встретили его невнятным весёлым лаем. Он прикрыл их от "мессершмиттов", когда они подходили к базе. Он один спустил в море двух "мессеров", третий задымил к горизонту.
>
> — Сода-виски, — предложили они ему.
>
> — Сода-солнце, — сказал он и стал губами ловить капли грибного дождя, залетавшие в открытую фрамугу.
>
> Американцам перевели — "сода-солнце", — они опять засмеялись и напились на радостях. Его стали звать "Сода-солнце".
>
> …
>
> А романов у него вовсе не было, и кто его "безоглядная любовь", никто не знал, и вина он не пил, только хватал губами капли дождя, когда возвращался с полёта без единой пробоины. И уходил он от "мессеров" всегда в сторону солнца. Блеснёт крылышками и растворится в слепящем диске.

*Грибной дождь* (literally "mushroom rain") is a phenomenon observed when it rains and the sun shines through openings in clouds at the same time.

So the protagonist jokingly calls "sun-soda" the sun-lit raindrops which he catches with his lips.